# MySQL - select rows via patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Take the following `patterns` table:

```
|   id   |   pattern                                                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0    |   date in {int} day|days|week|weeks|month|months|year|years   |
```

As you can see, the mock-up pattern in row `0` expects the third word to be an integer and the fourth word to match one within the stated collection.

How would I go about selecting rows, given an inputted sentence, that matches some type of regular expression residing in the `pattern` field (similar to how I expressed above), eg.

```
select * from patterns where match(pattern, 'date in 25 weeks');

# result - row with id: 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your patterns in regular expressions and then build a query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM patterns WHERE 'date in 25 weeks' REGEXP pattern;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions inside your query. There is [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) available for.